# Kotlin Jackson serilization wrong column order and nondeterministic

Tags: csv, kotlin, jackson

I'm having a strange issue with Kotlin Jackson serialization to a CSV.  When serializing to a CSV the column order output is incorrect **but only when one or more attributes has a capital letter**.  Even more bizarre is that the output order is **nondeterministic**.  Two back-to-back runs with the exact same values can produce different output orders.  Here is my example code:

```
package com.draper.surveillance.common

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper
import java.io.File


class MyClass(
   val zProp1: Int,
   val Prop2: Int,
   val Prop3: Int)

val csvMapper = CsvMapper().apply {
   disable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY)
}
val bootstrapSchema = csvMapper.schemaFor(MyClass::class.java)
   .withUseHeader(true)
val writer: ObjectWriter = csvMapper
   .writerFor(MyClass::class.java)
   .with(bootstrapSchema)

val sequenceWriter = writer.writeValues(File("test.csv"))
object Test {
   val l = listOf(
      MyClass(1,2,3),
      MyClass(4,5,6)
   )

   @JvmStatic
   fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      sequenceWriter.writeAll(l)
   }

}
```

If I run this once I might get

```
prop3,zprop1,prop2
3,1,2
6,4,5
```

and I run it again and I get

```
prop3,prop2,zprop1
3,2,1
6,5,4
```

You'll notice that it also lowercases the columns in the output.  I don't care about that.  But, if you make all the properties lowercase in the data class, the problem goes away and the csv always has the columns ordered as they are declared in the class.

I also tried putting `@JsonPropertyOrder("zProp1", "Prop2", "Prop3")` over `MyClass` but it just gets ignored.

Comment: After experimenting a bit with your code, and I can confirm that this is happening with jackson 2.13.0. Interestingly, using `@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic = true)` seems to result in the expected ordering. I recommend opening an issue at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues .  FWIW this *does not* happen with Java, so maybe it has to do with how Kotlin produces their bytecode?

Comment: Actually nevermind, I just managed to reproduce it with Java code. Seems to be a Jackson bug!

Comment: @Badashi thank you for confirming that this happens in Java as well.  I have filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/727)